# upload image with generated code from Postman does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to upload an image and set it to profiles of my teammates in some system.
I managed to perform this request and upload the images successfully using Postman but unfortunately it doesn't work when copying the generated code/writing it by myself in the IDE...

```
payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"PATH/TO/IMAGE.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"

headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'Authorization': "Basic 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Host': "<host.of.site>",
    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------613416014226243256356192",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Content-Length': "259378",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Here are their required fields from the documentation:

```
POST /api/gateway.php/sample/v1/employees/1/photo/ HTTP/1.0
Host: api.x.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----MultiPart-Mime-Boundary----
Content-Length: 520

------MultiPart-Mime-Boundary----
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="photo.jpg"
Content-Type: text/plain

... binary file data ...

------MultiPart-Mime-Boundary------
```

No matter what I do, still getting "400".
I would be grateful if someone here could help me! that'll be great!
Thanks ahead!

Comment: and if you try in your console?

Comment: File name and path are specified in the payload. I don't think that's how it's actually sent in a web browser. Can you do this on a browser with the network tab open. That'll give you a better idea of what's happening, because as far as I understand, when we're uploading some file, we'll be posting the raw binary data, not just the path to the file. If you've never used the network tools tab, check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) out.

Comment: Yep, already tried from the console...didn't work as well -.-

Comment: and I checked the developer tools while uploading the photo, saw  a different URL, but I get "403 - forbidden" when trying to use it in my code.
Any idea how do I get the binary data of the image you said?

Comment: edit: I'm trying to use the image's binary but still the same error.